# Jsch ChannelExec : How to pass a password to server after the command?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I would like to use a "scp" command from my java application Jsch and ChannelExec. Command is ok, but how do I pass my password ?

Directly on server it would go like this :

```
$ scp user@server:/myPath/* .
$ user@server's password:
(informations on files copied)
```

Command and password are on 2 separate lines.

To recreate this in java i did this :

```
ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec"); //$NON-NLS-1$
channelExec.setCommand(scpCommand);
channelExec.connect();
try (OutputStream outputStream = channelExec.getOutputStream()) {
    pause(5000);
    outputStream.write((password + "\n").getBytes()); //$NON-NLS-1$
    outputStream.flush();
}

(read result and terminate session)
```

But as you can guess it doesn't work.

Do you have clues on how to solve this ?
Should I pass the password in the command, separated by a special caracter ? ('\n' maybe I don't know)
Or is there another solution ?

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1):

Before connect, use the below code line.

```
channelExec.setPty(true);
```

For more details, refer below the documentation.
https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html#setPtyType-java.lang.String-

Comment: To explain: `scp` command can read the password from terminal only. Calling `setPty(true)` enables terminal emulation in Paramiko. In general, this can bring you lot of nasty side effects and should be avoided. With with `scp` it might be ok. +1